# Asp.net Core routing to another project

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have two project in a solution. **Project A** is admin interface **Project B** is user interface. I want to route mapping from **Project B** (user interface) to **Project A** with **/adminpanel**.

**Project A** is localhost:11111
**Project B** is localhost:22222

I want to link like this localhost:22222/adminpanel so i wanna access **Project A** controller /Home/Index

How can i do this ?

Comment: You have to provide more information than that.

Comment: @macit, What route mapping you mean? Project B and Project A will be in same domain?

Comment: yes same domain. im desinged layered pattern but i dont know how to merge projects.